# routing error in my console after installing ckeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ckeditor

**i am using rails 3.0.3 and i recently installed ckeditor to add text editor in my articles.before adding this editor everything was working fine.but after installing ckeditor(followed this : https://github.com/hificreative/rails-3-ckeditor) i am getting text editor in my articles page but i am getting routes error in console and i am not able to save data on clicking save button...**

---

**console output :**

```
Started GET "/javascripts/reset.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Mar 23 13:28:19 +0530 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/reset.js"):


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.5ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/grid.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Mar 23 13:28:19 +0530 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/grid.js"):


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/style.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Mar 23 13:28:19 +0530 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/style.js"):


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (2.2ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/style.js"):


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (2.2ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/messages.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Mar 23 13:28:19 +0530 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/messages.js"):


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.8ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/forms.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Mar 23 13:28:19 +0530 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/forms.js"):


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.4ms)
```

---

**i have included following in my gemfile :**

```
gem 'ckeditor', '3.5.0'
```

---

**following are the steps that i followed to install ckeditor:**

```
Next step is generate ckeditor js files and configuration file Check “config/initializers/ckeditor.rb” for more configuration options:

rails generate ckeditor:base

Generate ckeditor models for file upload support: For paperclip:

rails generate ckeditor:migration

For attachment_fu:

rails generate ckeditor:migration --backend=attachment_fu

Don’t forget about migration:

rake db:migarte
```

---

**included following line in my lauout.application.html.haml file**

```
= javascript_include_tag :ckeditor
```

**and wrote following line in my articles _form.html.haml file**

```
form.cktext_area :content
```

how to solve this error.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I just restarted my PC and then everything started working normally, without this error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can help with that particular gem but I just installed using this one with instant success.

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor